# Installing R in Anaconda is taking forever

Tags: r, anaconda, installation, delay

For some reason I had to uninstall `Anaconda` and reinstall. I am trying to install `R` again, but its taking forever. I started that in the morning (10 am) and it still says installing `R` (5 pm). I am not using `Anaconda prompt` but `Anaconda Navigator`. I have successfully done this before and it didn't take this much time the last time I did it. What do you guys think is the problem?

Answer (score 5):

The Anaconda **base** env is a massive environment with many packages installed by default. Similarly, metapackages like `r-essentials` involve installing many packages and sometimes it can be difficult to resolve a common denominator where none of the dependencies are in conflict. The easier path is to create the R env as a separate environment, rather than trying to install it in **base**.